# Query AD need nested group info

Tags: powershell, active-directory, nested

I have the following script, I need to also query to get a nested group if one exists and if so have the nested groupid and the nested group name included in the export below, if a nested group does not exist them I need to fill it in with an empty GUID.

This is what I have below.

```
$OU |
  ForEach {
    $countUser = (Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName).Count
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy, DistinguishedName, objectGUID -SearchBase $_ 
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $managedBy = $_.managedBy;
    $DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName;
    $GroupID = $_.objectGUID;

    if ($managedBy -ne $null) {
      $manager = (Get-ADUser -Identity $managedBy -Properties emailAddress, sn, displayName);
      $managerName = $manager.Name;
      $displayName = $manager.displayName
      $managerEmail = $manager.emailAddress;
      $managerID = $manager.objectGUID;
      $managerFName = $manager.givenName;
      $managerLName = $manager.sn;
      $managerDesc = $manager.description;
      $managertype = $manager.employeeType;
      $managerDistinguishedName = $manager.DistinguishedName;
    } else {
      $managerName = '';
      $managerEmail = '';
      $managerID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
      $managerFName = '';
      $managerLName = '';
      $managerDesc = '';
      $managertype = '';
    }
    Write-Output $_;
  } |
  Select-Object @{n='TASKIDID';e={$TaskID}}, @{n='GroupID';e={$GroupID}},
    @{n='Group Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='ManagerID';e={$managerID}},
    @{n='displayName';e={$displayName}},
    @{n='Managed By Email';e={$managerEmail}}, 
    @{n='Description';e={$managerDesc}},
    @{n='GroupDistinguishingName';e={$DistinguishedName}},
    @{n='managerDistinguishedName';e={managerDistinguishedName}} |
  Export-Csv c:\aatest\_GetGroupOwners.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How many levels deep? Just one?

Comment: *"I need to also query to get a nested group if one exists"* Nested where? How do you check for its existence?

Comment: Just 1 level down is all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need one level down you can get all the info you need from the current object the loop is on.

```
#If group member is a group grab its info
if($_.objectClass -eq "group"){
    #Do your stuff with the data in here
   $GroupName = $_.Name
   $GroupGUID = $_.objectGUID
}
```